# mysql field indexing

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table `products`, and I have columns like `product_name`, `product_id` AND `product_code`. 
What is the best way to index these three fields? Index them one by one, or should I create one index for the combination of the three? Keep in mind that there will be a search engine for listing my products with filters for these three fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always index different combinations of the columns **based on queries** which are affecting your table. Individual column indexes are uneffective.

Comment: if I create a combination of these three fields, will my search be faster if I search only after two of them? Or should I make more indexes, for combination of the three and combination of twos?

Comment: First you have to review all query which is working on this table, then you can create the necessary indexes. For example, if your query's WHERE clause affecting the column 'product_code' and the result contains the 'product_code' and 'product_name' column then you should create an index for 'product_code' and 'product_name' but be careful the order of the columns in the index is important! The most important thing is that you can't create indexes without examining your queries. Keep in mind: both underindexing and overindexing (INSERT, UPDATE performance) is bad!

Answer (score 0):

If the combination of columns is supposed to be unique then create a unique index with all three of the columns. Otherwise index the columns that are commonly used in queries. I don't think it really matters if you make a index containing many or one columns.